# Data augmentation on GPU

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, keras-layer

As tf.data augmentations are executed only on CPUs. I need a way to run certain augmentations on the TPU for an audio project.
For example,

> CPU: tf.recs read -> audio crop -> noise addition.
> TPU: spectogram -> Mixup Augmentation.

Most augmentations can be done as a Keras Layer on top of the model, but MixUp requires both changes in input as well as label.

Is there a way to do it using tf keras APIs.

And if there is any way we can transfer part of tf.data to run on TPU that will also be helpful.

Comment: It's ugly but you could provide labels as inputs to network

Comment: Thanks. Thought about this. why is all of tf.Data runs on CPU?. Is there anyway to transfer part of it?

Comment: I guess the idea is that when your GPU is under a lot of stress from training procedure, you can prepare (augment too) your data on CPU asynchronously. I think this is the main motivation behind it. Plus, not all kind of augmentation can be done (or are worth to be done) on GPU. I don't know about TPUs but you can do direct data augmentation on GPU with NVIDIA DALI

Answer (score 2):

As you have rightly mentioned and as per the Tensorflow documentation also the preprocessing of `tf.data` is done on CPU only.
However, you can do some workaround to preprocess your `tf.data` using `TPU/GPU` by directly using transformation function in your model with something like below code.

```
input = tf.keras.layers.Input((512,512,3))
x = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(transform)(input)
```

You can follow [this](https://www.kaggle.com/c/flower-classification-with-tpus/discussion/132191) `Kaggle` post for detailed discussion on this topic.

Comment: The augmentation Mixup, doesnt just change the input image, but also labels. I wanted to do: a*img1 + (1-a)*img2 and a*label1+(1-a)*label2. Using lamda we can do image augmentation not the labels.

Answer (score 2):

See the Tensorflow guide that discusses [preprocessing data before the model or inside the model](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/preprocessing_layers#preprocessing_data_before_the_model_or_inside_the_model). By including preprocessing inside the model, the GPU is leveraged instead of the CPU, it makes the model portable, and it helps reduce the training/serving skew. The guide also has multiple recipes to get you started too. It doesn't explicitly state this works for a TPU but it can be tried.